# Devtools does not survol (fly over) the page

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

You have an idea of why the devtools does not "survol (fly over)" the page and "pushes" upward ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lojj7.png)

Comment: Click the three-dot icon in the top-right corner and change "docking" to "float".

Comment: Yes it works, but I would like to know the cause

Comment: The cause is this is how it works I guess.